# Deny access to one particular subpath for spring cloud gateway route

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We're using Spring Cloud Gateway in front of our backend services. We have a route similar to the following:

```
  routes:
    - id: foobar-service
      uri: lb://foobar-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/foobar/**
      filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
```

We want to deny access to one particular subpath (e.g. `/foobar/baz/**`) but leave the rest open. Is it possible to do this using the YAML syntax? Perhaps we need to implement the routes using the Fluent API instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  routes:
    - id: foobar-baz-service
      uri: no://op
      predicates:
        - Path=/foobar/baz/**
      filters:
        - SetStatus=403
    - id: foobar-service
      uri: lb://foobar-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/foobar/**
      filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
```

Comment: Ah, a separate route. I was fixated on trying to update the predicate on the first route. Thanks spencergibb!

Comment: I have the same requirement, but to do with the api code.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my experience with the API implementation with a single route.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes( final RouteLocatorBuilder locatorBuilder ) {
    RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder builder = locatorBuilder.routes();
    builder.route(p -> p //
                    .path(getAllowedPaths()) //
                    .and() //
                    .not(n -> n.path(getRestrictedPaths()) //
                    .filters(f -> f //
                            //filters
                    .uri(uri)));
    return builder.build();
}
```